# Awaiting a task not behaving the way I would expect

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, win-universal-app

I have a code path which is not behaving the way I would expect; I possibly have a bug, but I suspect it's more likely that there is something about awaiting a task that I misunderstand.  The aim of the following code is to navigate to a second screen and then, based on a timeout, navigate back again and try to share some content:

```
AdvertHelper adHelper = new AdvertHelper();

Task nav = new Task(async () =>
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Call Navigate to MainPageViewModel");
        Navigation.Navigate<MainPageViewModel>();

        saved = await SaveVideo();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After SaveVideo()");
    });
});
adHelper.DisplayAdvert(this, nav);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Before await nav (saved: {saved})");
await nav;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"After await nav (saved: {saved})");
```

`DisplayAdvert` looks like this:

```
    public void DisplayAdvert(BaseViewModel sourceVM, Task afterAdvert)
    {                        
        _afterShow = afterAdvert;
        _tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
        _tmr.Tick += _tmr_Tick;
        _tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        _tmr.Start();

        Navigation.Navigate<AdvertViewModel>();
    }
```

and the timeout:

```
    private void _tmr_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {            
        _afterShow.Start();
        _tmr.Stop();
    }
```

So, my understanding is that I have created a task that will navigate to the `MainPageViewModel`, then attempt to save the video (for the purpose of this, imagine the SaveVideo() simply returns true in an async function after a period of several seconds.

From the debugging:

```
Before await nav (saved: False)
Call Navigate to MainPageViewModel
SaveVideo() Called
After await nav (saved: False)
SaveVideo() Return true
After SaveVideo()
```

So, if I'm reading this correctly, the code is not awaiting the task `nav` (and therefore SaveVide()), but is continuing and therefore not getting the result of SaveVideo() at the correct time.

Comment: There are three awaits in that code. At least one of them is at the root of the strangeness. Meaning, see if you can simplify this a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem you're seeing is that the `Task` constructor does not understand `async` delegates. [You should never, ever use the `Task` constructor; as I describe on my blog, there are no use cases for it. Ever.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html)

> The aim of the following code is to navigate to a second screen and then, based on a timeout, navigate back again and try to share some content

Then why not something like this?

```
Navigation.Navigate<AdvertViewModel>();
await Task.Delay(2);
Navigation.Navigate<MainPageViewModel>();
saved = await SaveVideo();
```